# Style for a <div> to simulate the behaviour of a pop-up windows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my application, I have a tag  where I load the content of several jsp files. I wish to define in my css file a style  for this tag to get a look that have a resemblance with a pop-up windows. Is there any way to accomplish this?

**UPDATE 1**

The code of my page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <title>HorarioLivre</title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>  
    <script>
     $(function() {
            $('a').click(function() {
                $('#result').load($(this).attr('href'));
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-main.css">
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <h1><a href="index.html">HorarioLivre</a></h1>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="listagem_evento.html" class="icon evento">Eventos</a></li>
          <li><a href="cadastra_horario.html" class="icon horario">Cadastrar Horarios</a></li>
          <li><a href="listagem_horario.html" class="icon horario">Listar Horarios</a></li>
          <li><a href="listagem_usuario.html" class="icon usuario">Usuarios</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">${usuario.nome}</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="usuario_perfil.html" id="perfil" class="icon perfil">Perfil</a></li>
                <li><a href="usuario_config.html" id="settings" class="icon settings">Configura&ccedil;&otilde;es</a></li>
                <li><a href="usuario_logoff.html" id="logout" class="icon logout">Sair</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div id="result"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <title>HorarioLivre</title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="index.js"></script>

    <script>
     $(function() {
            $('a').click(function() {
                $('#content').load($(this).attr('href'));
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-popup.css">
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <h1><a href="index.html">HorarioLivre</a></h1>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="listagem_evento.html" id="popup" class="icon evento">Eventos</a></li>
          <li><a href="cadastra_horario.html" id="popup" class="icon horario">Cadastrar Horarios</a></li>
          <li><a href="listagem_horario.html" id="popup" class="icon horario">Listar Horarios</a></li>
          <li><a href="listagem_usuario.html" id="popup" class="icon usuario">Usuarios</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">${usuario.nome}</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="usuario_perfil.html" id="popup perfil" class="icon perfil">Perfil</a></li>
                <li><a href="usuario_config.html" id="popup settings" class="icon settings">Configura&ccedil;&otilde;es</a></li>
                <li><a href="usuario_logoff.html" id="popup logout" class="icon logout">Sair</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div id="results">
    <a href="#" id="close">Close</a>
    <div id="content"></div><br />
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE 3**

This is my javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   setupPopup();

   $('#search').submit(function() {
      $('#content').html('Test data');
      return false;
   });
   return false;
});

function setupPopup() {
   $('#popup').click(function() {
      $('#container').append('<div id="cover">');
      $('#results').fadeIn(500);
      popupPosition();
   });

   $('#close').click(function() {
      $('#results').fadeOut(100);
      $('#cover').remove();
   });

   $(window).bind('resize', popupPosition);
}

function popupPosition() {
   if(!$("#results").is(':visible')){ return; }

   $("#results").css({
      left: ($(window).width() - $('#results').width()) / 2,
      top: ($(window).width() - $('#results').width()) / 7,
      position:'absolute'
   });

   $('#results').draggable();
}
```

**UPDATE 4**

After many changes in my html and javascript code, this update come bring the more recent version from my code. In this version, seems that the webapp is ignoring the inclusion of my script file js/index.js, since none of it is running,  and when I click on the link, the page is opened in the brownser window, and not in the pop-up window.

JSP:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <title>HorarioLivre</title>

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/index.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-popup.css">
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <h1><a href="#">HorarioLivre</a></h1>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="listagem_evento.html" class="icon evento">Eventos</a></li>
          <li><a href="cadastra_horario.html" class="icon horario">Cadastrar Horarios</a></li>
          <li><a href="listagem_horario.html" class="icon horario">Listar Horarios</a></li>
          <li><a href="listagem_usuario.html" class="icon usuario">Usuarios</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">${usuario.nome}</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="usuario_perfil.html" class="icon perfil">Perfil</a></li>
                <li><a href="usuario_config.html" class="icon settings">Configura&ccedil;&otilde;es</a></li>
                <li><a href="usuario_logoff.html" class="icon logout">Sair</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div id="results">
        <a href="#" id="close">Fechar</a>
        <div id="content"></div> 
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   setupPopup();
});

function setupPopup() {
   $('a').click(function() {
       $('#content').load($(this).attr('href'));
      $('#container').append('<div id="cover">');
      $('#results').fadeIn(500);
      popupPosition();
   });

   $('#close').click(function() {
      $('#results').fadeOut(100);
      $('#cover').remove();
   });

   $(window).bind('resize', popupPosition);
}

function popupPosition() {
   if(!$("#results").is(':visible')){ return; }

   $("#results").css({
      left: ($(window).width() - $('#results').width()) / 2,
      top: ($(window).width() - $('#results').width()) / 7,
      position:'absolute'
   });

   $('#results').draggable();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you, I wrote a popup box in javascript

https://github.com/corcorans/rcoffee/tree/master/popup

It handles the re sizing of the popup window depending on the content and the size of the browser window.

```
$('a').on('click', function() {
   $('#content').load($(this).attr('href'));
   $('#container').append('<div id="cover">');
   $('#results').fadeIn(500);
   popupPosition();

   $('#close').on('click', function() {
      $('#results').fadeOut(100);
      $('#cover').remove();
   });

   $(window).bind('resize', popupPosition);
});
```

Comment: Ok, you example is very closer of the my objective. Is there any way to allow the popup be moved across the screen?

Comment: Okay, the changes are up there check the index.html and index.js. Let me know how that works for you.

Comment: Hi again. I added the code for my page. Any thoughts about how make the integration with the nice code you write? what I should change in your code, since it's based in a form, while mine is based in hyperlinks?

Comment: Follow the functions I created and add them where needed. So, once you click the element, perform the popup functions that I provided.

Comment: So where I do $('#popup').click({}); is where you want to start

Comment: Ok, I made some updates in my code (see UPDATE 2). I added id=popup for try match the hyperlink with the code $('#popup').click, and made some changes in the <div>. But the page are not working now (it was working before).

Comment: what does your index.js look like?

Comment: You need to change my code to fit your needs, not to copy

Comment: And I did some changes in the javascript code; basicly I change the id searchForm for container, but don't worked. Any ideas for which value I should use?

Comment: You wouldn't need the $('#search').click() because that is for a form submission which you are not doing

Comment: I'll modify my answer for you

Comment: Hoping this is my last update, I add to my original question a fourth one, with my most recent code, which have an odd issue: apparently it isn't recognizing the command <script src=js/index.js></script> (at least was what I am guessing, since when I running the app, the links are opened as if no script existed. Any idea what's happening?

Comment: Can you open developer tools on chrome and see if it can find to index.js file?

Comment: I use the Firefox's network monitor and I can see that the the index.js is loaded correctly, then I still don't understand why this code don't work. I try put a simplest code directly in the jsp page (using the tag <script></script>, and works. But when I use the option of include a external file, isn't working.

Comment: This is a link-only answer, and the link is dead.

Answer (score 1):

In any case, you just need to mess around with your div's styles in a stylesheet.

If you're going for a 'modal' type of pop-up then there's really no specific way of styling it, it's generally open for interpretation. Though most pop-ups in this fashion use a form of overlay in the background it's not entirely necessary.

If you're going for a more traditional approach like a javascript popup window, you would have to carefully dissect the visual aspects of the popup and go from there.

Comment: What i want is something very similar to this: http://www.codesoaked.com/css-snippets/css-popup-window.html, but I wish the popup could be moved across the screen (I will add some menus and toolbars, and will simulate a title bar, to try get the look of an child window we get used to see in desktop applications).

Comment: For the record, that plugin does not work on the latest version of chrome or firefox. however I see your point, I will edit my comment accordingly.